# validating custom field in wordpress using javascript

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, validation

I have add jquery lib to wordpress for adding javascript validation in custom form. Only 1st field of validation is working other validation error is not shown.I have add jquery in function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_nifty_scripts' );
   function my_nifty_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('my-nifty-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js',
   false, null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('my-nifty-custom'); 
}
```

Html code of my home page:-

```
  <form  method="POST"  name="adminprofForm" onsubmit="return(validateAdminprofile());">

            <div class="claim-form">
                <div class="claim-form-label">Your Name </div>
                 <input type="text" name="yourename" id="yourename" />
                 <div id="unameError"></div>    
                <?php if(!empty($nameError)){ print_r($nameError);}?>
            </div>

            <div class="claim-form">
                <div class="claim-form-label">Your contact telephone number</div>
                 <input type="text" name="phoneno" />
                  <?php if(!empty($phoneError)){ print_r($phoneError);}?>
            </div>

            <div class="claim-form">
                <div class="claim-form-label">Your email address</div>
               <input type="text" name="email" />
                <?php if(!empty($emailError)){ print_r($emailError);}?>
            </div>
            <div class="claim-form">
                <div class="claim-form-label">Accident or illness</div>
                 <input type="text" name="type" />
                <?php if(!empty($typeError)){ print_r($typeError);}?>
            </div>
            <div class="claim-form">
                <div class="claim-form-label">Best time to call</div>
               <input type="text" name="time" />
                <?php if(!empty($timeError)){ print_r($timeError);}?>
           </div>
            <div class="claim-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="claim-form-submit-btn" />
            </div>
            </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function validateAdminprofile()
{   

    var chk = 0;
    var patternProfname = /^[A-Z a-z]{3,35}$/i;
    var textProfname = document.getElementById("yourename");        
    if($("#yourename").val()==""){
    alert("Enter your name");
    //$("#unameError").css("color","red").html("Enter your name");
    //$("#gotop").click();
    chk = chk +1;
    }
    else if(!patternProfname.test(textProfname.value)){
    alert("Enter your valid name");
    //$("#unameError").css("color","red").html("Enter valid name");
    //$("#gotop").click();
    chk = chk +1;
    }
    var patternProfemail =/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
    var textProfemail = document.getElementById("youreemail");              
    if($("#youreemail").val()==""){
    alert("Enter your name");   
    //$("#uemailError").css("color","red").html("Enter admin email id");
    //$("#gotop").click();
    chk = chk +1;
    }
    else if(!patternProfemail.test(textProfemail.value)){
    alert("Enter your valid email");    
    //$("#uemailError").css("color","red").html("Enter valid email id");
    //$("#gotop").click();
    chk = chk +1;
    }   

    //else $("#unameError").html("");

    if(chk==0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I only see it validating for name and email in the javascript code... you said the phone number field was not validating? Could that be because there's no validation code written for it? I may be misunderstanding what you're saying, though.

Comment: I would like to tell only validation for empty field of name is working its not working for valid name and other field also